# html5 audio player on autoplay is not working

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I am using html5 audio player which was working perfectly some weeks ago now on

```
autoplay="autoplay"
```

this is going to play double audio and also controls are not working.
Not sure whats the problem

Here is player

```
http://simplepodcaster.com/one-girl-two-boots/
```

Also i tried to check in firebug but not see any error.

Regards,

Mohammad Umer

Comment: Autoplay worked, you have two playing at the same time, also you should check [**how to ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - we shouldn't need to access an external site to reproduce your issue

Comment: How i am two playing at same time?? Sorry about external link but i was not sure how to show the issue

Comment: You have script for SPPP Audio Player and Clammit Sound Manager.

Comment: A [working answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36712338/2206209) given in your other question, the question is not relevant your problem though. It should be **`autoplay` played twice while using a `audioPlayer` plugin.**