# html5 player with autoload not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am using this html5 audio player

`http://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly`

I have problem with that.

When i put there "autoload" its not working and player play two time.

**Here is html5 code:**

```
 <audio autoplay="autoplay" preload="none" controls="" class="sppaudioplayer" id="spp-audio-player"><source src="http://www.blogtalkradio.com/girlsinheels/2016/04/12/one-girl-two-boots.mp3"></source></audio>
```

**Here is javascript code:**

```
 $( function()
    {
        $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer();
    });
```

**Here is fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bcHsy/40/

Comment: Which AudioPlayer did you use?

Comment: @DestinatioN he uses the following plugin: http://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly . Mohammad, the fiddle provided works, so could you please explain in wich browser it isn't working?

Comment: i checked it at Mozilla firefox and i did not able to pause audio. Also I can hear two voices.

Comment: @Boratzan Which browser you checked? Please check player can play and pause the audio ?

Comment: @Boratzan Also at chrome you can hear two voices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to solve this issue since yesterday. Finally I have found that there is a bug in your `audioPlayer` plugin. I am not going to fix that, you can report on their plugin page.

The problem is when you add `autoplay` into your `<audio>` tag the browser starts playing the audio and also your plugin start the same. As a result you have played twice your track. You can fix this using the following method.

1. Remove `autoplay` from your `<audio>` tag.
2. Add `$('.audioplayer-playpause').trigger('click');` after `$( 'audio' ).audioPlayer();`

P.S: The solution is only based on your `audioPlayer` plugin.

The final solution will be:

**html5 code:**

```
<audio preload="none" controls="" class="sppaudioplayer" id="spp-audio-player"><source src="http://www.blogtalkradio.com/girlsinheels/2016/04/12/one-girl-two-boots.mp3"></source></audio>
```

**javascript code:**

```
$( function()
{
    $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer();
    $('.audioplayer-playpause').trigger('click');
});
```

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bcHsy/45/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <audio autoplay preload="auto" controls="" class="sppaudioplayer" id="spp-audio-player">
 <source src="http://www.blogtalkradio.com/girlsinheels/2016/04/12/one-girl-two-boots.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Try with above code. This will work fine. JQuery is not required to initiate audio player. HTML5 will take care of that.

Comment: Sorry but  if i did not use jQuery to initate player then the css not works :(

Answer (score 0):

Also, as per the plugin script, you can add the "loop" attribute as shown below, to avoid getting it played two times.

```
<audio autoplay preload="auto" loop="" controls="" class="sppaudioplayer" id="spp-audio-player">
 <source src="http://www.blogtalkradio.com/girlsinheels/2016/04/12/one-girl-two-boots.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```